# Quiver vector from high value toward low value

Tags: python, vector, direction

What I would like to plot is to make vector from high values to low values.
If code would start from:

```
a = [[1, 8, 9, 10],[2, 15, 3, -1],[3,1,6,11],[13,15,5,-2]]
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(4), np.arange(4))
U = ?
V = ?
```

From this point, I should set `U` and `V` components of the vector.
The magnitude of each point would be `a[x][y]`. I don't have much idea of how I can set `U` and `V` to make arrow from high to low value at each grid point.

Comment: Do you mean you want to construct the vector that points from the coordinates of the highest value in your array to the coordinates of the lowest value in your array?  A "vector from from high values to low values" seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: Hi Brionius, You are correct. I would like to make the vector that points from cordinates with the higher value in the array to the coordinates of the lower value such as converging and diverging of wind or flux. Thank you for your help to clarify my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (doesn't require numpy):

```
import itertools as it

a = [[1, 8, 9, 10],[2, 15, 3, -1],[3,1,6,11],[13,15,5,-2]]
rowSize = len(a[0])

maxVal = a[0][0]
maxIndex = 0
minVal = a[0][0]
minIndex = 0

for k, v in enumerate(it.chain(*a)):  # Loop through a flattened list of the values in the array, and locate the indices of the max and min values.
    if v > maxVal:
        maxVal = v
        maxIndex = k    
    if v < minVal:
        minVal = v
        minIndex = k

U = (minIndex % rowSize) - (maxIndex % rowSize)
V = (minIndex / rowSize) - (maxIndex / rowSize)

print U, ",", V
```

#### OUTPUT

```
2 , 2
```

Note that you haven't defined what behavior you want when there are two equal maximum values, as there are in your example.  The code above uses the "first" (upper-leftmost) one as the true maximum, and ignores all others.

#### Explanation:

I flattened the list (which means I read the values like you would the words on a book - first the first row, then the second row, then the third row).  Each value got a single index, like so:

```
0  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15
```

For example, a value in the second row and the third column would get an index of 6, since it's the 7th value if you read the array like a book.

At the end, when we've found the index of the max or min value, we need to get 2D coordinates from the 1D index.  So, we can use the mod operator (%) to get the x-value.

For example, `6 % 4 = 2`, so `X = 2` (the 3rd column)

To get the Y value, we use the integer division operator (/).

For example, `6 / 4 = 1`, so `Y = 1` (the second row)

The formulas for `U` and `V` are simply taking the X and Y values for the max and min and subtracting them to get the vector coordinates, like so:

```
U = xMin - xMax
V = yMin - yMax
```

If you're wondering, "why the heck didn't he just use the meshgrid solution I started with", there are two reasons:  One, using a non-standard library like numpy is generally undesirable if there is an easy way to solve the problem without non-standard libraries, and two, if you ever need to deal with large arrays, generating a large meshgrid could become time/memory expensive.

### Solution that picks shortest vector:

```
import itertools as it

a = [[1, 8, 9, 10],[2, 15, 3, -1],[3,1,6,11],[13,15,5,-2]]
rowSize = len(a[0])

values = sorted(enumerate(it.chain(*a)), key=lambda x:x[1])  # Pair each value with its 1D index, then sort the list.

minVal = values[0][1]
maxVal = values[-1][1]

maxIndices = map(lambda x:x[0], filter(lambda x:x[1]==maxVal, values))  # Get a list of all the indices that match the maximum value
minIndices = map(lambda x:x[0], filter(lambda x:x[1]==minVal, values))  # Get a list of all the indices that match the minimum value

def getVector(index1, index2, rowSize):  # A function that translates a pair of 1D index values to a "quiver vector"
    return ((index1 % rowSize) - (index2 % rowSize), (index1 / rowSize) - (index2 / rowSize))

vectors = [getVector(k2, k1, rowSize) for k1, k2 in it.product(maxIndices, minIndices)]  # produce a list of the vectors formed by all possible combinations of the 1D indices for maximum and minimum values

U, V = sorted(vectors, key=lambda x:(x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1])**0.5)[0]

print U, ",", V
```

#### OUTPUT

```
2 , 0
```

Comment: Thank you Brionius, To be honest with you, I didn't much understand min and maxIndex in your U and V formula and how you define U and V with those index. Could you explain more in detail. Thank you again.

Comment: @Isaac Sure - I added an explanation section - see if that helps you understand.  If you want, I can show you how to solve the problem using your meshgrid idea.

Comment: Another questions, is is possible that vector would be towward the coordinate of the closer highest value if there are more than one higher values.